# Implementation of personalization builder scenarios topviews/topseller/new releases/... unclear

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

Recently i was asking myself how the scenarios are really implemented by Salesforce. The reason for this is that you will not find any good explanation how the scenarios are implemented, i only found superficial ones.

Some Examples for my questions that cannot be answered by the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_einstein_recommendation_scenarios.htm&type=5):

**new releases:**

- What does count as new release?

  - Somewhere I have seen information that it will only add items where the ReleaseDate is within the past 14 days.
  - When this is correct can I change this time period? What happens if 120 items share the same timestamp of releasedate - which one will be kept in the scenario and which one will be kicked out?
- Will it just inherit the newest 100 elements (because of the cap size of 100 elements per scenario?
- Which item gets kicked first when 120 items share the same releasedate which is the newest?

**topseller:**

- Which time period is the basis for this scenario?
- Is there even a time period or does the system only analyze the last 100000 purchases or something like this?

**topviews:**

- Same question as topseller mapped to views.

**top grossing:**

- How is the revenue calculated?

  - Is this just purchases times selling price (even if it varies?)?
  - Or does salesforce somehow normalize or do other stuff?

**bought bought last cart:**

- How long does the system keep your last cart entry?
- Does it even look for your last cart entry or does it process the last item in the pipe delimited list of your recommendation call (parameter cart)?

**bought bought last purchase:**

- How long does the system keep your last purchase?
- Documentation tells us the following:

  > Subscribers or visitors who bought the item last purchased also bought these items.
- Is it really only the last purchased **item**? Or is it a typo and it should be items?
- As far as I see i do not have the option to have a scenario: bought bought last purchase (complete order). Am I overlooking something?

If you are able to answer those it would be great, furthermore it would be great if you could tell me where you got these information from.